# Why is the order of evaluation different for Collections than for other types using the conditional operator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, operator-precedence

While trying to implement a GetHashCode override similar to Jon's Skeet's suggestion in [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416) I noticed some odd behavior in the order of evaluation that is causing a syntax error when doing a null check on a collection property in the class using the conditional operator.

Consider the following:

```
public class Foo
{

    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public List<String> Bar { get; private set; }

    public override Int32 GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + this.Name == null ? 0 : this.Name.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.Bar == null ? 0 : this.Bar.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

This code will not compile as you get a syntax error on `hash = hash * 23 + this.Bar == null ? 0 : this.Bar.GetHashCode();`, specifically pointing too the `hash * 23 + this.Bar` segment.

The error is

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

You do not get the same error on `hash = hash * 23 + this.Name == null ? 0 : this.Name.GetHashCode();` although the only difference is `Name` is a `string` and `Bar` is a `List<>`.

Wrapping the entire conditional operation in a set of parenthesis does remove the error, but that still doesn't explain why the collection property is being treated differently than the string property.

Is there a reason that I'm not aware of that cause the operation to be evaluated differently for different types?

Comment: Submit this to an obfuscated C# contest.

Comment: In general, when you come across such "differences" you should start with the opposite stance, that they're treated the same. This might give you a hint as to why things behave the way they do. In this case, you are given the hint that `+` between an int and a list does not work. So why does `+` work between an int and a string?

Comment: The * and + operators always take precedence over the ?: operator, but the + operator is overloaded on strings as a concatenation function. Since there is an implicit conversion from int to string, your first statement evaluates to a conditional expression where a string is compared to null, whereas your second fails to compile because there is no conversion from int to List<string> defined for the + operator to use. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @PrestonGuillot no one has mentioned that, I think it would be worth including it as an answer because obviously part of my problem is I assumed that the `?:` operator would take precedence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `hash * 23 + this.Name == null` is a valid expression, whereas `hash * 23 + this.Bar == null` is not. `+` is used both for arithmetic and for string concatenation, but not for adding elements to a list. In both cases, the whole of `hash * 23 + this.... == null` is taken as the condition of the `?:` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this function:

```
void Crash() {
    int hash = 123;
    int crash = hash * 23 + this.Name == null ? 0 : this.Name.GetHashCode();
}
```

It is similar to yours - I removed the part that does not compile.

This function will crash when `Name` is set to `null` [(demo)](http://ideone.com/QGyOR4), in the same way that your `GetHashCode()` would. This appears odd, because at the first glance the check for `null`-ness is there.

However, it is a wrong thing that's being checked for `null`: C# compares to `null` this entire expression:

```
hash * 23 + this.Name
```

This is a valid *string concatenation*.

This provides a clue to solving your "mystery": it isn't the fact that `Bar` is a collection that leads to a compile error by mistake, but the fact that `Name` is a `string` that avoids a compile error by mistake.